# How to rank values in a data frame rowwise using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

The question is straightforward. I started using dplyr but cannot come up with a solution of how to rank the values in each row. The ultimate goal would be to assign a rank to each value and for each row. I tried the following that didn't work:

```
mat_agg %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_each(funs(rank))
```

An example is:

```
matrix(c(1,0,0.5,0.5, 0, 1),nrow=2)
```

The desired outcome would be:

```
matrix(c(1,3,2,2, 3, 1),nrow=2)
```

I very much appreciate any help. Thank you!

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output for others to test your code.  I would assume it to work with `?do`

Comment: Did you try `arrange`? Here is [how to make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example/5965451#5965451).

Comment: If you're just working with a matrix rather than a data frame, you probably don't want to use dplyr (though you may if your real example is more complex)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. How would you solve it using dplyr on data frames?

Comment: Added a solution with `dplyr` (as you asked for it)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `apply()` in combination with `rank()`. We negate `m` to get descending order, and transpose the output to get desired structure.

```
t(apply(-m,1,rank))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    2    3
#[2,]    3    2    1
```

Answer (score 3):

If we are using `dplyr`, convert the `matrix` to `data.frame`, and use `do` with `rowwise`

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(m1) %>%
         rowwise() %>% 
         do(data.frame(t(rank(-unlist(.)))))
#      X1    X2    X3
#  (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1     1     2     3
#2     3     2     1
```